# Child component not re-rendering even though parent state is updated using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a functional component `App` with a `useEffect` hook and I'm trying to get the `<Redirect>` child component to re-render on a state change, specifically the call to `setUserInSystem`, which should update `userInSystem`, which is explicitly referenced in the render method. However the component does not re-render when `userInSystem` changes and I can't figure out why. (Note: both async functions `getUserInfo` and `getUserByWorkEmail` are working as expected and retrieving correct data.)

```
const App = (props) => {
  const { authState, authData } = props;
  const [signedIn, setSignedIn] = useState(false);
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(undefined);
  const [userInSystem, setUserInSystem] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSignedIn(!(authState !== 'signedIn'));
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      const data = await getUserInfo();
      const userFound = await getUserByWorkEmail(data);
      setUserInSystem(userFound);
      setUserInfo(data);
    };
    if (authState === 'signedIn') {
      fetchUser();
    }
  }, [authState]);


return (
    <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
            <Redirect
                exact={true}
                path="/"
                to={userInSystem ? '/dashboard' : '/unverified'}
            />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </LayoutProvider>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new hook and envelope the Redirect with a condition that is mutated every fetch:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
```

In the fetch setLoading to false after the fetch is resolved.

```
const fetchUser = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      const data = await getUserInfo();
      const userFound = await getUserByWorkEmail(data);
      setUserInSystem(userFound);
      setUserInfo(data);
      setLoading(false);
    };
```

Then in the return:

```
<Switch>
{ !loading ? <Redirect
            exact={true}
            path="/"
            to={userInSystem ? '/dashboard' : '/unverified'}
        /> 
        : <div>Loading....</div> 
}
</Switch>
```

Comment: Do you happen to know why `setUserInSystem` or `setUserInfo` doesn't cause a rerender?

Comment: It has to come down with something of Redirect component, if it was a normal component it would rerender as you are setting a prop that is used for the component (userInSystem). But maybe the redirect, or the switch, has some logic between that prevents simple rerenders. @jQwierdy

Answer (score 0):

Try adding userInSystem in the useEffect dependency array.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setSignedIn(!(authState !== 'signedIn'));
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      const data = await getUserInfo();
      const userFound = await getUserByWorkEmail(data);
      setUserInSystem(userFound);
      setUserInfo(data);
    };
    if (authState === 'signedIn') {
      fetchUser();
    }
  }, [authState, ***userInSystem***]);
```